# On update or create post redirect to current post position in list

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, admin

Is there a way to redirect the user to the current location in the list of the post he has updated? We have a CPT with more than 200 items and there are editors who need to review all items after a certain period.

When you hit the update button (change status) it redirects to the overview and to the first item in the list. What we want to do is when the editor hits the button it redirects to the post overview, and goes the position of the edited item. In this way can see where he is and goes on to the next one.

The default behaviour of WordPress is not really userfriendly. We already changed the screensetting to 250 items on 1 page. But thats also not really a solution for this UX issue.

Comment: Do you mean - for examples - to show 20 posts per page in the WP admin "list" - and if you edit a post which is on the 5th page, after saving you return to the 5th page list? Or perhaps you can clarify - or better show graphics / images to make your question clearer.

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean. And even better scroll down to the edited post.